# "I never wanted to be found" or "I don't want to be found again?" Which is correct?

Tags: american-english

I tried to find it's meaning on but I didn't. Please tell me which is correct and what's the meaning of first one?

Comment: Is this said of someone who has run away from home or from a bad relationship, and thus does not want to be found (discovered)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "never wanted to be found" means, that sometime in the past, at a specific event, occurrence, one wanted not to be found, as in, not seen, not heard, so that others had no idea where he/she was. 
The "I don't want to be found" means that in the present, in the moment, one does not want to be found again. It implies, that sometime in the past, the person had already been in a situation where he wanted to not be found, yet he was. Because of this, now, he doesn't want something like that to happen again.
Both of the two constructions are correct.